# Unmount 'SUSPENDED' zfs pool from failed device

Tags: mount, usb-drive, zfs

I run zfs on a LUKS device hosted on a single USB-device. The device failed (probably bad cable/connection, because the disk reads fine on another machine).

But how do I --force GNU/Linux to forget the device?

```
$ zpool status

  pool: freenetpool
 state: SUSPENDED
status: One or more devices are faulted in response to IO failures.
action: Make sure the affected devices are connected, then run 'zpool clear'.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-HC
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 0 days 05:09:40 with 0 errors on Sun May 10 05:37:46 2020
config:

        NAME         STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        freenetpool  DEGRADED     0     0     0
          freenet    DEGRADED     3   344     0  too many errors

errors: 5263 data errors, use '-v' for a list

$ sudo zpool export freenetpool
umount: /freenet: target is busy.
cannot unmount '/freenet': umount failed
$ lsof /freenet | field 2 | grep -v PID | uniq | xargs kill -9
$ sudo umount -l /freenet/
(OK)
$ sudo zpool export freenetpool
cannot export 'freenetpool': pool I/O is currently suspended
$ sudo zpool clear freenetpool
cannot clear errors for freenetpool: I/O error
$ sudo zpool clear -F freenetpool
cannot clear errors for freenetpool: I/O error
$ sudo zpool clear -FX freenetpool
cannot clear errors for freenetpool: I/O error
$ sudo zpool clear -nFX freenetpool
(OK)
$ sudo zfs unmount /freenet
cannot unmount '/freenet': not a mountpoint
$ sudo zpool destroy -f freenetpool
cannot open 'freenetpool': pool I/O is currently suspended
$ zpool detach  freenetpool freenet
cannot detach freenet: pool I/O is currently suspended
$ zpool remove freenetpool freenet
cannot remove freenet: pool I/O is currently suspended
$ zpool remove freenetpool /dev/mapper/freenet
cannot remove /dev/mapper/freenet: pool I/O is currently suspended
$ zpool set cachefile=/etc/zfs/zpool.cache freenetpool
cannot set property for 'freenetpool': pool I/O is currently suspended
```

I can reboot the machine but I really would like to know a way to avoid rebooting.

Comment: On UNIX, `zfs unmount -f mountpount` works. If forced unmounting is not supported on Linux, you could send a defect report to the Linux kernel people.

Comment: `$ sudo zfs unmount -f /freenet` gives `cannot unmount '/freenet': not a mountpoint`. This could be because I `umount -l`'ed the dir.

Comment: Is this a ZFS mount point? .... see `zfs list`.

Comment: `/freenet` is the only mount point in `freenetpool`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the pool is suspended, there is no way to unsuspend it. You will have to reboot the machine.

Comment: I have the feeling you may be right, but do you have an authoritative source for that? It seems a bit silly if you cannot tell zfs to fugetaboutit.

Comment: Yes, it is a known long standing issue: https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/5242